# Data Not Showing Up From A For Loop

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a product recommender in my shopping cart, something similar to when you go to the grocery store and pickup candy as an impulse.

It looks like below.  When I click on the dropdown menu, it does not dropdown with the data I am looking for.

I am using the following code that I would think would input this data:

````php
                     <?php foreach($Fluoros['Fluoro'] as $Fluoro) {
                     echo $Fluoro['Fluoro'], '<br>';
                     }
                    ?>

                    <select title="Add Fluoro To Your Cart" id="<?php echo $Fluoro['Description']; ?>" class="selectpicker white-drop crimp-part" data-width="auto">

                       <select title="Select Fluoro" id="<?php echo $Fluoros['Product']; ?>" class="selectpicker white-drop crimp-part" data-width="auto">
                       <?php foreach($Fluoros['Product'] as $Fluoro){
                        echo '<option ' . 'value = ' . $Fluoro['Fluoro'] . ' </option>';
                        } 

                        ?>
                        </select> ``` 

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXygI.png

The data is being pulled in my "Cart " class. The Select statement below works and brings the correct results

 ```php 
public function fluoroCart() {
    $getFluoroProducts = $this->_db->query("SELECT i.Part_Number, i.Description
                           FROM Inventory i
                                             INNER JOIN Product_Details pd on pd.Part_Number = i.Part_Number
                                             WHERE pd.Category_ID = 15");

     $fluoroProducts = $this->_db->results();

      foreach($fluoroProducts as $Fluoro){

    $Flouros [] = array( 'Fluoro'=>$Fluoro->Part_Number, 'Description'=>$Fluoro->Description);

      }

    }```
````

Comment: You have a `<select>` inside another `<select>` - not valid. Also, your `<option` needs to have a `>` at the end: `<option>`

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, select option values need to be surrounded by quotes. Also, in addition to indicating a value, you need to put some text between the opening and closing option tags for it to actually show up in the menu.

```
<select>
<option value="some value">Some Value Text</option>
</select>
```

You need to modify your PHP like this

```
echo '<option value = "' . $Fluoro['Fluoro'] . '">'.$Fluoro['Fluoro'].' </option>';
```